# RichFaces fileUpload unable to invoke listener

Tags: java, file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

For `<rich:fileUpload>` I'm unable to invoke `listener`. When I checked in firebug console I found that its going in infinite `GET` requests loop.

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
    <param-value>1000000000</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Facelet:

```
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"
                ontyperejected="alert('Only JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP files are accepted');" maxFilesQuantity="5">
                <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="info" />
        </rich:fileUpload>
    </h:form>
```

Backing Bean:

```
public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception{
UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
uploadFile.setLength(item.getData().length);
uploadFile.setName(item.getName());
uploadFile.setData(item.getData());
writeFile();
}

public void writeFile() {  

FileOutputStream fop = null;  
File file;
try {

    file = new File(fPath + uploadFile.getName());
    logger.info(fPath + uploadFile.getName());

    fop = new FileOutputStream(file);  
    if (!file.exists()) {  
        file.createNewFile();  
    }  

    fop.write(uploadFile.getData());  
    fop.flush();  
    fop.close();    

} catch (IOException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  

} finally {  
    try {  
        if (fop != null) {  
            fop.close();  
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

I checked a lot of similar questions but didn't got any clue !

I'm using RichFaces version 4.2.2

Comment: Try with a simple `<h:form>` around it.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy That's how I'm using it.

Comment: try without `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy tried that too !

Comment: Can you show more information about your backing bean ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy What exactly do you want to know about the backing bean code. I've already posted the code I'm using for `fileUpload`.

Comment: Is there anything else the fileUpload that is not working? Maybe something wront inside web.xml or faces-config.xml.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I don't think its something from web.xml or faces-config as I've properly checked it by refering several posts and richfaces documentation.

Comment: What exactly is the resource being requested in the GET requests? The upload is supposed to be a POST. Why have you opted to not create temp files in your cfg? I'll recommend you get it working with temp files enabled first

Comment: @kolossus Well I thought the same way, and tried to put `method="post"` inside `<h:form>` however it didn't made any difference. So when I checked docs, it explicitly states that. `The value of the "method" attribute must be "post"`. So I believe its implicitly `method="post"`. For the temp files, I already tried making it `true`, however as I said its in infinite loop, I'm unable to get the file either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove following lines form your web.xml,
somebody fix by doing that.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Seam Multipart Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Seam Multipart Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.seam</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```